# Can avg. Vel. be zero in uniformly accelerated straight line motion?

Tags: kinematics, soft-question

A particle moves in a straight line with constant acceleration. The average velocity of this particle in an interval is zero.

According to me it may become possible when velocity of particle is in opposite direction and a constant acceleration starts opposite to velocity and make particle move opposite to its initial direction.

Then an interval from this part containing negative and positive velocity may contribute to zero airthmetic mean.

Am i correct ??

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Feel free to answer your own question with some equations and figures showing it.

Comment: @rmhleo I can show figures by images but how can i improve my math jax to show equations related to question ( I badly need to learn it)

Comment: The best resource for MathJax is probably the tutorial [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) over on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: There is a difference between `uniform straight-line motion` and `uniformly-accelerated straight-line motion`. Uniform motion implies constant velocity. I believe you need to edit your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example:

If I throw a ball vertically upwards then (neglecting air resistance) it moves in a straight line with the constant acceleration $-g$. At some time $T$ later the ball falls back down and I catch it. The displacement in the time $T$ is zero because the ball started in my hand and finished in my hand, so the average velocity is zero divided by $T$ and this is zero.

In general your requirement for a zero average velocity over some time $T$ just means the position of the moving object at $t = 0$ must be the same as the position at $t = T$.